# Whenever i use xxx.join() it never works

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

Whenever i use xxx.join() it never works, eitehr just stops and doesnt carry on the rest of the code or crashes my program. in this case crashing my program. i usually make do without it, but for my current program i am trying to allow the client to wait for a message from the server, and i need .join() to allow this without crashing. new_message only crashes my program and doesnt allow the new gui to form.
No errors come up in terminal, just crashes

```
        def email_verify_gui():
            # new gui
            email_entry.destroy()
            username_entry.destroy()
            createpassword_entry.destroy()
            confirmpassword_entry.destroy()
            invalid_passwords.destroy()
            invalid_boxes.destroy()
            next_button.destroy()

            S2.configure(text="Verify your email.")
            img2 = customtkinter.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open("emailverify2.png"), size=(250, 175))
            subtitle = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame_signup, text=("Complete the tab we opened "
                                                                         "so that we can verify your email."),
                                              text_color="#fff", font=("Century Gothic", 16), wraplength=300)
            subtitle.place(x=27, y=90)
            email_img = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame_signup, image=img2, text="")
            email_img.place(x=35, y=130)

        def server_email():
            server_email_status = False
            client.send(("send email").encode())
            client.send(new_email.encode())
            print(new_email)
            file_path = "C:\\Users\\gunne\\PycharmProjects\\Playground\\email verification html.html"
            webbrowser.open(file_path, new=2)

        def new_message():
            while True:
                server_verify_message = client.recv(2048).decode()
                if server_verify_message:
                    print(server_verify_message)
                    break


        thread_email_verify_gui = threading.Thread(target=email_verify_gui)
        thread_server_email = threading.Thread(target=server_email)
        thread_new_message = threading.Thread(target=new_message)
        print("Threads Established")

        thread_email_verify_gui.start()
        #thread_email_verify_gui.join()
        print("STAGE 1")

        thread_server_email.start()
        #thread_server_email.join()
        print("STAGE 2")
```

works without the .join() but crashes my program still for as long as i use new_message()

Comment: Define "crashes".

Comment: You appear to want to `join` the `thread_email_verify_gui` thread and the `thread_server_email` thread _immediately_ after `start`ing each of them. What's the point in that? Why not simply _call_ `email_verify_gui` and `server_email` instead?

Comment: @SolomonSlow I think he want to prevent the gui to freeze during the process.

Comment: yup, and also crashes it just freezing (not responding)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `ThreadPoolExecutor` to achieve this basicaly it's allow you to add a call back on a thread.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor 
def email_verify_gui():
            # new gui
            email_entry.destroy()
            username_entry.destroy()
            createpassword_entry.destroy()
            confirmpassword_entry.destroy()
            invalid_passwords.destroy()
            invalid_boxes.destroy()
            next_button.destroy()

            S2.configure(text="Verify your email.")
            img2 = customtkinter.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open("emailverify2.png"), size=(250, 175))
            subtitle = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame_signup, text=("Complete the tab we opened "
                                                                         "so that we can verify your email."),
                                              text_color="#fff", font=("Century Gothic", 16), wraplength=300)
            subtitle.place(x=27, y=90)
            email_img = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame_signup, image=img2, text="")
            email_img.place(x=35, y=130)

        def server_email():
            server_email_status = False
            client.send(("send email").encode())
            client.send(new_email.encode())
            print(new_email)
            file_path = "C:\\Users\\gunne\\PycharmProjects\\Playground\\email verification html.html"
            webbrowser.open(file_path, new=2)

        def new_message():
            while True:
                server_verify_message = client.recv(2048).decode()
                if server_verify_message:
                    print(server_verify_message)
                    break

        
        executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)

        future = executor.submit(email_verify_gui)
        future.add_done_callback(lambda x:server_email)
        future.add_done_callback(lambda x:new_message)
```

For more information -> https://superfastpython.com/threadpoolexecutor-in-python

Comment: i can do that sure, but its just annoying that i cant wait for threads to finish before initiating the next line of main code. makes everything unsteady. but thank you!

Comment: If that's what you want you can use `Queue` to track the progression of your thread. If you confirm that what you need i can update my response in this way :)

Comment: If my response fit your answer mind accept it to help other ;) @ImTooMad